# AppBar command Navigation Issue in Metro apps?

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, appbar

I have a metro application in which I have AppBar in my home-page.Here each AppBarCommand will have different functionality,like if I click on each AppBarCommand they will load different listviews in my homepage.But here my problem is when I click on each listview-item it has  to navigate to other page,First AppBarCommand is working fine in my application,But from second AppBarCommand onwords loading listviews is working fine but clicking of that listview-items will terminating my application.I have tried so much but unable to solve this issue.Below I tried to give you my scenario.
Can anyone give me some helpful advice.
Thank you![image]

Comment: Need to see code.  Where are you configuring the appbar initially? How are you navigating to a new page? What does the code in the appbar button handlers look like?

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT,Am calling my services under AppBarCommands click,then my page-control loads listviews and then I have to navigate to different pages if I click on listview-items,But actually its getting terminated.what should I do for this?

Comment: @AkilPandu - is there a compelling reason why you're loading several ListViews on the same page, rather than either navigating to a new page with that ListView, or using the same ListView, but updating the datasource?

Answer (score 0):

The application is being terminated whenever an unhandled exception occurs. Run your app in debug mode to see the exception and this will help you figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the EventListener for ItemInvoked and adding it again? It would be nice to see some code!